# What's the connection between even/odd harmonics and even/odd (transfer) functions?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, even-and-odd-functions

What's the connection between even/odd harmonics and even/odd (transfer) functions?

Why do they correspond to each other?

Particularly, if the transfer function is/contains even or odd functions, then why does this lead to the output signal having even or odd functions correspondingly?

Harmonics are the components of a signal that exist as integer multiples of the signal. Even harmonics are: $2f, 4f, ...$, odd are: $1f, 3f, ...$.

[A transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) is some sort of "mapping" that usually applies some sort of "effect" to a signal, e.g. an audio signal. It's often a Fourier transform of some input function.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. A typical meaning of transfer function is the Laplace transform of a linear system, so there are no harmonics as such. Perhaps you could elaborate what you mean by harmonics & transfer functions.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example? "Transfer function" is a *very* broad term.

Comment: @Rahul A transfer function that produces harmonic distortion. Then it's known that it e.g. produces only even or odd harmonics based on whether it contains even or odd functions respectively. but what's the connection between "contains even or odd functions AND produces even or odd harmonics"?

Comment: It's likely that the transfer function is a Fourier transform (a sum of sines and cosines) and if it's even, then there's only cosines, if it's odd, then there are only sines. And then the transfer function only maps either the even or odd part respectively. But the details are still remaining.

Answer (score 1):

There are only so many words available to scientists and mathematicians. Sometimes the same words are appropriated for many different purposes. In this case, "even--odd" is appropriated for many different dichotomies: even and odd integers; even and odd functions; even and odd harmonics. From a linguistic point of view, it might be fun to think about whether there are any more mathematical uses of "even--odd" to represent a dichotomy. But from a mathematical point of view, there's no real significance.

Comment: But there's some connection: https://www.moz.ac.at/sem/lehre/lib/pd-sounddesign/even_and_odd_functions.html#Harmonics

Comment: Then you should ask a sound designer. To a mathematician, as I said, there's no real significance.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/add-odd-even-harmonics-to-signal

Comment: Perhaps the explanation is found in Fourier representation of $f$:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/321396/248602